# calculating the residue of a complex function in an integral

Tags: residue-calculus

I wonder how to solve this integral:
$$P(q, \omega) = \frac{-2i}{(2\pi)^4}\times\int\frac{\mathrm d\mathbf{k}~\mathrm d\omega' e^{i\omega'\eta/h}}{\left[\omega' - E(\mathbf k) + i\delta\operatorname{sgn}\left(E(\mathbf k) - \mu\right)\right]\cdot\left[\omega + \omega' - E(\mathbf k + \mathbf q) + i\delta\operatorname{sgn}(E(\mathbf k + \mathbf q) - \mu)\right]}$$

for the poles below (which are not in the contour):
$$\begin{align}\omega' &= E(\mathbf k) - i\delta\operatorname{sgn}(E(\mathbf k) - \mu)\\
\omega' &= E(\mathbf k + \mathbf q) - \omega - i\delta\operatorname{sgn}(E(\mathbf k + \mathbf q) - \mu)
\end{align}$$

The contour is:
$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: I ported your math to $\LaTeX$, please check for its correctness when the edit comes through. I was not sure about this part: $e^{i\omega'\eta/h}$. I also kept the bold (for $\mathbf k$ and $\mathbf q$).

Comment: thanks for your cooperation booooys.